# SQL Server-How can I make a varchar auto increment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run the following script but it is failing and I do not know why:

```
DROP TABLE table;
CREATE SEQUENCE seq START WITH 0;
CREATE TABLE table (
    id VARCHAR(512) PRIMARY KEY AS ('0000000000' + CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR seq AS VARCHAR(512)), 10),
    field VARCHAR(512),
    field VARCHAR(512)
);
```

I want to cast the number to string in order to match the requirements of other part of the code

Comment: Why you want to store it in this way?

Comment: `NEXT VALUE FOR` cannot be used in a computed column. You can use this expression as a `DEFAULT`, but clients would be able to supply their own value. Gordon's answer is a better idea.

Comment: When designing your database, you should focus on the *data*, not any particular *representation* of that data that is used for e.g. presentation purposes. If it's a number, store it as a number. The fact that someone wants to see it with some number of `0`s on it in some context should be *irrelevant* to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a different approach?  Just use an `identity` column for the table.  Then add a generated column that provides your string representation:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    t_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    t_id_str as (right('0000000000' + CAST(t_id AS VARCHAR(512)), 10))
);
```

Comment: Why storing redundant data?

Comment: @Jens: computed columns don't take up storage, unless they're marked `PERSISTED` (or when included in an index).